# show multiple layers in open layers2

Tags: openlayers

I am using open layers2

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>webgis</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <style>
div {
  height: 641px;
}
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="map" style="">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("map",{projection:new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")})
    osmLayer=new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OSM")
    map.addLayer(osmLayer)
    map.setCenter([0,0],1)
    controls=[new OpenLayers.Control.OverviewMap(),
    new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),
    new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher()]
    map.addControls(controls)
    wms=new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("iran",
    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms/",
    {LAYERS:'python:iran_location'},
    {isBaseLayer:false});
    map.addLayer(wms)
    </script>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

so when i open my browser

it first show openstreetmap

and it disappear in seconds and just show one layer

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the base layer below the top layer the top layer will need some opacity, and you can also try to make the white background of the WMS transparent, for example

```
wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("iran",
"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms/",
{LAYERS:'python:iran_location', transparent: true},
{opacity: 0.5, isBaseLayer:false});
```